# 500 error when binding index and other routes to a single callback in Bottle

Tags: python, routes, bottle

Following this tutorial:

http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#request-routing

It shows the example:

```
@route('/')
@route('/hello/<name>')
def greet(name='Stranger'):
    return template('Hello {{name}}, how are you?', name=name)
```

And states:

> This example demonstrates two things: You can bind more than one route
>   to a single callback, and you can add wildcards to URLs and access
>   them via keyword arguments.

I'm trying to test this with the following code but I am getting a 500 error when accessing the index eg `/`.

```
import bottle
import pymongo

custom = bottle

@custom.route('/')
@custom.route('/hello/<name>')
@custom.view('page2.tpl')
def index(name):

    # code

bottle.run(host='localhost', port=8082)
```

The error only seems to occur when accessing the site's index, eg `/`.

The index does not work in the following example, but the other two routes do.

```
import bottle
import pymongo

custom = bottle

@custom.route('/') # this doesn't work
@custom.route('/milo/<name>') # this works
@custom.route('/hello/<name>') # this works
@custom.view('page2.tpl')
def index(name):

    # code

bottle.run(host='localhost', port=8082)
```

**Solution**

```
import bottle
import pymongo

custom = bottle

@custom.route('/')
@custom.route('/milo/<name>')
@custom.route('/hello/<name>')
@custom.view('page2.tpl')
def index(name="nowhere"):

    # code

bottle.run(host='localhost', port=8082)
```

`nowhere` is output unless one of the first two routes are used, in which case that value is overwritten by whatever `<name>` is.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It can be tricky to debug 500 errors, but if you can get other scripts to work, then my guess is that the problem is because you didn't define a default value for the `name` argument in your index function.  When you access the route, the function is called.  But if you access `/`, there's no value for the `name` argument, so an error is raised when the function is called.

This is why the example you pasted has `def greet(name='Stranger'):`.  The `name='Stranger'` sets a default name that will be used if no name is passed in.  Try adding that to your function and see if it fixes it.

You might want to turn on [debug mode](http://bottlepy.org/docs/dev/tutorial.html#debug-mode) when debugging your bottle script, as it makes the error messages more helpful.

Comment: That was it, I will paste the solution in the OP and can accept your answer in 6 mins.